# Differences between Standard for Software Component Testing (BCS, SIGIST, 2001) and BS 7925-2:1998

Tags: unit-tests, standards

What (if any) are the differences between [The Standard for Software Component Testing](http://www.testingstandards.co.uk/Component%20Testing.pdf) (from the British Computing Society SIGIST and available for free) and BS 7925-2 (which is available to purchase for £170)?

Comment: what's the reason for the unit tests tag? Your question doesn't mention unit testing specifically, so I'm confused why you've dropped it into that category.

Comment: because both are standards for component testing, whereby a component is the smallest possible part of code for a specification unit.

Answer (score 2):

The first document appears to be the last draft version of the published (expensive) version - in fact, this page states that and appears (to my reading) to be recommending that you use the draft: http://www.testingstandards.co.uk/bs_7925-2.htm

What reasons do you have for using either standard at all?

Neither will help you to fulfil your stakeholders' needs for relevant, timely, quality-related information - only you can do that, by doing a good job of discussing their needs with them, analysing the testing problems that you have, and staying in close communication with them during the course of the project.

If your stakeholders have specific needs for following a particular standard, then you need to explain the context for that before anybody can help you.

Comment: I thought that was the case from my own reading. Thats why I was asking what the difference between the two is. I didn't ask if either would help me fulfil a stakeholders need for relevant, timely, quality related information. This question doesn't have a specific context, I'm interested in knowing the difference between two standards (if any ?)

Comment: Okay, well, in order to get useful replies, I'd suggest that you edit your original question to include that information. Because that's how it reads currently - you're asking for a favour here (i.e. you want people to put time into writing you an answer), don't make us guess! :)

Comment: I'll edit it now, sorry it didn't seem clear enough.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the edit. Hopefully someone will be able to answer without forking out £170!

Answer (score 1):

You probably better spend 164 CHF and purchase the draft ISO 29119 parts 2 & 3 (parts 1 & 4 are still not for sale), it is partially based on BS 7925-2 and might replace it in the future.
I'm reading it now, and it seems they did a good job with it, it gives you the right foundation but leaves a lot of context to be added.